# How to display a confirmation dialog when user click button in Isolated components in react app (Next Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm maintaining global flag when there is a form has some and preventing route changes but i have some isolated components which has certain button clicks (6 buttons) that i need to prevent when form has changes.

At the moment i'm checking `formHasChange` on every button click methods and getting confirmation and executing event. For that i have implemented wrapper button component to check the condition and get user confirmation. I would like to know is the any other best way to achieve this ?

Below is wrapper component

```js
import React, { Children, isValidElement, cloneElement, SyntheticEvent } from 'react';

const EventWrapper = ({ children, onClick, hasChange }) => {
  function areYouSure(event) {
    if (hasChange) {
      return confirm('Are you sure want to discard changes ?') ? onClick(event) : event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      onClick(event);
    }
  }

  const childrenWithProps = Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (isValidElement(child)) {
      return cloneElement(child, { onClick: (event: SyntheticEvent) => areYouSure(event) });
    }
    return child;
  });

  return <>{childrenWithProps}</>;
};

export default EventWrapper;
```

Below hook used for the prevent rout changes

```js
import Router from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useBeforeUnload } from 'react-use';
import { useSettings } from './useSettings';
import themeConfig from 'src/config/themeConfig';
import nProgress from 'nprogress';

const useUnsaveChangeConfirm = (isConfirm = true, message = 'Are you sure want to leave this page?') => {
  const { settings, saveSettings } = useSettings();

  useBeforeUnload(isConfirm, message);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      if (isConfirm && !window.confirm(message)) {
        if (settings.routingLoader) {
          nProgress.done();
        }
        throw 'Route Canceled due to unsaved changes';
      }
    };

    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handler);

    return () => {
      Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handler);
      saveSettings({ ...settings, routingLoader: themeConfig.routingLoader });
    };
  }, [isConfirm, message]);
};

export default useUnsaveChangeConfirm;
```